# IIS7.5 - Configure impersonation whilst using an app pool configured with a named domain account

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-7.5

I am deploying a .NET web service that connects to a database.

When a user within the domain connects to the webservice, I want their identity to be known by the webservice (since a subsequent call to the DB from the webservice uses a USER_ID() function to know which user is making the request).

The app pool that is running the web service is configured to run under a domain account that allows access to the database. When I query the web service, it is connecting as that account of the app pool, and not the user that is calling the web service.

I have tried various different impersonation configurations but I can't get the web service to interpret the caller's identity. Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong? Is the fact that my app pool that is running under a named account causing the problem? Should it be configured to something else?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the app pool's problem. Impersonation has to be also set from configuration files which in fact, it's probably already been specified.

Now, you didn't mention what of service you are using. For the service to be aware of who is making the request through impersonation the service must be running in asp.net compatibility mode so it can participate in the asp.net pipeline. It's a pretty basic topic, but if you need more info, then refer to the MSDN article below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Leo